# @media hidden and visible mobile & desktop

Tags: css, media-queries, joomla3.0, hidden, css-transforms

I am brand new to @media queries and only got to do with it when my Joomla page wasn't displaying correctly on mobile and tablet. I have read as much as I could find but still have an issue with a desktop background and a header image that isn't displaying on tablet and mobile devices.
What I understand is that there are parameters set in the css code for diff widths of how the site will look. I have gone through my code (thousands of times) and tried to make the images visible on tablet and mobile by adding to the img code the visibility:visible statement: like this
     img {
     visibility:visible; 
     width: auto;
     height: auto;
     max-width: 90%;
    }
It doesn't make a difference

What I am wondering and this part I do not understand is if it has to do with the code set prior to @media (max-width: 480px) that is causing the images not to display.
This code: 
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

```
.hidden-desktop {
    display: inherit !important;
}
.visible-desktop {
    display: none !important;
}
.visible-tablet {
    display: inherit !important;
}
.hidden-tablet {
    display: none !important;
}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.hidden-desktop {
    display: inherit !important;
}
.visible-desktop {
    display: none !important;
}
.visible-phone {
    display: inherit !important;
}
.hidden-phone {
    display: none !important;
}
}
```

Please can someone help me to understand what about this I can change..there isn't anything that I want to hide from mobile or tablet and rather re-size the images than it not show.

Comment: Can you please add some example HTML? I'm having a hard time understanding the exact problem - maybe there is a way to achieve what you want without all these classes.

Answer (score 0):

I used to run into this too, although @media (max-width: 767px) technically should work.

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) could be a workaround, it always works for me.

And also make sure you have this meta tag included in your html page header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

Comment: Here my test site url: you will see on the tablet and on mobile the background image as well as the header image is not displayed...http://www.utv-racing.co.za/test/   I have raked the code now for 2 weeks have no idea what is prohibiting those images to show on mobile and tablet